# Simpler git-flow model, am I doing it right?

Tags: git, github, branching, gitflow

I'm trying to implement a branching model that is similar to git-flow, but simpler (no `release` or `hotfix` branches).

The idea is to have the `master` branch always up to date with the latest tagged release, a `develop` branch that runs parallel to it, and `feature` branches to implement longer (more than 1-2 commits) features.

`develop` branches from `master` and back into it, while the `feature` branches do the same in the `develop` branch.

This is my branching model:

```
# 1. While in master, create develop branch, and track it.
# This branch is created once here.
git checkout -b develop
git push --set-upstream origin develop

# 2. Do some minor work and push to develop
git add <file>
git commit -m 'did work'
git push

# 3. To work on a feature, create a branch from develop, and track it
git checkout -b feat/issue9
git push --set-upstream origin feat/issue9

# 4. After work on feature is finished, merge into develop
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feat/issue9
# Delete remote and local branches
git push origin --delete feat/issue9
git branch -d feat/issue9
git push

# 5. Once a new release is ready, bump version
git add __version__
git commit -m 'Bumped version number to 0.1'

# 6. Add tag
git tag -a v0.1
git push --tags

# 7. Merge develop into master, and push changes
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff develop
git push
```

Up to this point, the branches look like this:

[image]

This is almost what I want, except that `develop` is behind `master` by two commits (the bumping of `__version__` file, and the merging of `develop` into `master`)

So I try to bring `develop` up to where `master` is:

```
# 8. Merge master into develop
git co develop
git merge master
git push
```

which results in this:

[image]

Once this point is reached, I start again from `2. Do some minor work and push to develop`. A second cycle looks then like this:

[image]

Is this a sensible model to be following? Can it give me problems in the future? Any tips to improve it?

Comment: I think there are a remarkable number of sensible models, especially when you tailor them to your work flow.  However, I find the wording on [this one](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) wondefully clear.  I think it's nothing but an extension of yours to handle a few cases you may not have had to deal with yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider not having the develop branch but using a staging server for that environment.

Yes work in branches of course but merge them into master in groups and tag the group with a version.

Then choose when to deploy what version to staging and production servers.

This is the [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) which works well for Pull Requests and is the basic workflow I have seen in the last 3 companies I've worked in.

The workflow you described in your question is the [gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) which has the develop branch and can be more suitable to larger organizations that have more contributors and more defined and/or more formal release processes.

There's also the [forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow) for distributed and open source communities.  You see this used with a lot of the open source gems